# Avoid column ambiguity on join by setting default table with laravel's query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-query-builder

I want to order a query (from `revenues` table) by relationship's column ('orders.number'). One order has many revenues. The problem is that both revenues and orders share a common column (`description`) which causes ambiguity on filtering by `where()`. I know I can specify the tables when filtering, but the issue here is that I'm using a global scope which orders the query by preset columns in a config file and `description` is one of them. I couldn't previously know the table name and sending it as a parameter to the function seems like an overkill for me.

```
$revenues = App\Revenue::
    with('order.client', 'order.place')
    ->sessionSearch('revenues')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->join('orders', 'orders.id', '=', 'revenues.order_id')
    ->select('revenues.*', 'orders.number as order_number')
    ->orderBy('order_number', 'desc')
    ->paginate(perPage());
```

I tried dynamically adding the table name in the `sessionSearch()` method, but I couldn't access it via the passed `Builder` instance, becuase it was protected.

I also thought that by performing a `leftJoin` mysql would know which my main table is and presumably target its columns, but ambiguity is still an issue.

Is there a way I can set a favorable table by default in my sql settings so that no ambiguity is caused? Basically I only need the number from the orders table, but ambiguity error is still being thrown.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: There's no concept of "default table if ambiguous" in MySQL AFAIK. You are responsible to be explicit enough to not have any ambiguities. I know this is not what you want to hear but you need to make it work somehow, perhaps by setting the explicit table name in the scope.

Comment: 1. what does session search do. 2. can you post the exact error so we can provide the proper help. 3. in general it seems like you have a lot of misconceptions about the query builder and mysql lets clear those out, provide the last part and i will when time is provide an answer if no one has.

Comment: @MartinHenriksen 1. `sessionSearch` literally performs a multiple `where()` filtering on a model class by attributes of that class, which are preset in a config file (hence not to change).
2. The problem is that a column named `description` is common in `revenues` and `orders` table and is being included in the where filtering by the `sessionSearch` method. Since the attribute is only being refered to by its name, it appears ambiguous once I join the `orders` table. I'm not on my computer these days, so I'm unable to provide the exact error code, but that was pretty much it.